# Linq How to run queries in chunks

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I have bundle of delete queries like following :-

```
DELETE FROM [Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 
  AND EmployeeId IN (3, 4, 6, 7, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22,....100 more) 
  AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' 
  AND Entry_Method = 'I'
```

SO in my code, i run this list of queries as below :-

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
        {
            foreach (var item in queries)
            {
                ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item);
            }
        }
```

But due to the large number of queries executing it creates a lock on sql, so i decided to execute the queries in chunk, so i found the below code :-

```
SET ROWCOUNT 500
delete_more:
DELETE FROM [Entry] 
    WHERE CompanyId = 1 
      AND EmployeeId IN (3, 4, 6, 7, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22,....100 more) 
      AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' 
      AND Entry_Method = 'I'
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 GOTO delete_more
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Now the problem is How do i run this thing as i was running it previously through `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`?

What is the way i can run this chunk query code in Linq?

Comment: Did you try just putting that whole statement in a string and running that using `ExecuteSqlCommand`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I will surely try this.

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn;t work for me. Do you get an error or does it not do what you expect? I have no idea if it actually works. It just makes sense to me that it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a SQL Server stored procedure that get the employee ids as a parameter. Let's call it 'sp_deleteEmployees' with the param `@ids`

Then in C# you create a string on the ids

```
string idsList = "3, 4, 6, 7, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22"
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("usp_CreateAuthor @ids={0} ", idsList);
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I guess I didn't understand the problem. If you need to delete the employees in chunk you can split the list of employee with this

```
public static List<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int length)
{
    var count = source.Count();
    var numberOfPartitions = count / length + ( count % length > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    List<IEnumerable<T>> result= new List<IEnumerable<T>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPartitions; i++)
    {
        result.Add(source.Skip(length*i).Take(length));
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can use this method to split the list to small chunks and delete them one chunk at a time

Comment: This thing works. but didn't solve my actual problem. But i will raise a different question.

Comment: sorry, i guess i didint understund the problem.

Comment: Here is new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41436449/linq-how-to-prevent-locks-when-bulk-delete

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!